# Struggling with an altitude problem in a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I'm having some trouble solving the following problem about heights in a triangle:

> 19. Two of the heights in a triangle do not intersect each other, and the acute angle between their extensions is 45°. Then, which of the
>     following statements is true?

> (a) one of the angles of the triangle is 45°;

> (b) one of the angles of the triangle is 135°;

> (c) it is not possible to determine;

> (d) there is no such triangle.

I have attached a diagram of the triangle that I received from someone who tried to help me with the problem. As they explained, if the heights a and c are extended and intersect at a 45-degree angle, the red triangle formed has an angle of 45 degrees (the same applies to heights c and b). However, this does not apply when the heights a and b are extended and intersect at a 45-degree angle. "The answer is therefore C."

[image]

Although the explanation was helpful, I still don't understand how to apply it to the problem. Can someone provide a more detailed explanation or guide me on how to solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Instead of re-posting your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4689529/409), you should simply edit the original to provide the new context. After all, you previous received multiple answers to the question, so there's a danger that a new reader with inadvertently spend time and effort duplicating an answer you found unsatisfactory. (Note that edits get "bumped" to the top of the Unanswered Queue, so you get that benefit of a re-post without cluttering the site with copies. Note also, however, that non-substantial edits *just* to trigger a bump are discouraged.) ... Good luck!